# Question on the proof of strong Markov property

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-process

I am studying strong Markov property and the following question came up.

Let $ Y_{ s}( \omega)$ be a bounded jointly measurable stochastic process and $ X_{ s}( \omega) $ be a standard Brownian motion for $ s \geq 0$, $\omega \in \Omega$ . Let $ P^ { x}$ be the probability associated with the Browman motion starting at $ x \in \mathbb R$ and $ E^{ x}$ be the corresponding expectation. Finally, let $\tau$ be a stopping time and  $\mathcal F_{\tau}$ be the associated sigma-algebra.

I want to show:

> $$ \phi (X _{\tau},\tau) \ \text{ is} \ \mathcal F_{\tau } \ \text{ measurable on }\{\tau < \infty \}\ \text{ where }  \ \phi ( y, s):= E ^{ y} [ Y_{ s}]$$ for $ s \geq 0$ and $y \in \mathbb R$.

I know that $\tau$ and $X_{\tau} 1_{\tau < \infty}$ are $\mathcal F_{\tau}$ measurable and want to use this fact, but I cannot proceed on.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: When you say that $Y$ is (jointly) measurable process, is it with respect to the filtration $\mathcal{F}$ ?

Comment: @TheBridge Yes, the big one

Comment: $\phi(X_{\tau},\tau) = E^{X_{\tau}}[Y_{\tau}]$ is the composition of $y\mapsto E^yY_{\tau}$ (which is non-random, so its measurability is not an issue) and $\omega \mapsto X_{\tau}(\omega)$. So you only have to show that $X_{\tau}$ is $\mathcal{F}_{\tau}$ measurable.

Comment: @Sayantan We are not considering such composition; we take expectaion of each section of $Y$ and then insert randomness again in two different places. I edited question to be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with the following solution.

It suffices to show $\phi$ is jointly Borel m'ble.

Let a random variable $Y$ be called *special* if $Y(\omega)=\prod_{i=1} ^m f_i(\omega(t_i))$ for some $f_i \in C_b(\mathbb R)$ and $t_i \geq 0$. In other words, $Y=\prod _{i=1} ^m f_i \circ \pi_{t_i}$ where $\pi_{t_i}$ is projection onto time $t_i$ i.e., $\pi_{t_i} (\omega) := \omega(t_i)$.

$B \subseteq \Omega$ is a *finite dimensional set* if $B=\bigcap_{i=1}^m \pi_{t_i}^{-1}(A_i)$ for some $t_i \geq 0$ and open sets $A_i \subseteq \mathbb R$.

**STEP 1**

Consider the case $Y_s(\omega)=f(s)Y(\omega)$ for some $f \in C_b(\mathbb R)$ and $Y$ special.

Using DCT, it can be shown that $y \mapsto E^y(Y)$ is continuous since $Y$ is special .

Then $\phi(y,t)=f(s)E^y(Y)$ is continuous, hence measurable.

**STEP2**

Consider the case $Y_s(\omega)= 1 _U Y$ for some open set $U \subset \mathbb R$.

It is a fact that $ 1_U$ is a monotone pointwise limit of continuous bounded functions. (generally holds in LCH spaces using Urysohn lemma, but can be explicitly constructed in metric spaces)

Then, using STEP1,  $\phi(y,t)=1_U E^y(Y)$ is pointwise limit of measurable functions, hence measurable.

**STEP3**

Consider the case $Y_s(\omega)=1_U(s) 1_B(\omega)$ for some open $U\subseteq \mathbb R$ and finite dimensional $B=\bigcap_{i=1}^m \pi_{t_i}^{-1}(A_i)$.

*Claim*: $1_B$ is monotone pointwise limit of some special random variables.

*proof*. \begin{align} 1_B &=1_{\bigcap_{i=1}^m \pi_{t_i}^{-1}(A_i)} = \prod_{i=1}^m 1_{A_i} \circ \pi_{t_i}
\\&= \prod_{i=1}^m  \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n^{(i)} \circ \pi_{t_i}
= \lim_{n \to \infty} \prod_{i=1}^m   f_n^{(i)} \circ \pi_{t_i}
\end{align}
for some $f_n^{(i)} \in C_b(\mathbb R)$ such that $f_n^{(i)} \uparrow 1_{A_i} $ as $n \to \infty$ for each $i$.  ////

Then, using STEP2 and MCT, $\phi(y,t)=1_U(t) E^y 1_B$ is monotone pointwise limit of measurable functions, hence measurable.

**STEP4**

Now, we can use the monotone class theorem. 
Note that $\mathcal P = \{U\times B: U \text{ open in } \mathbb R , B \text{ is finite dimensional}\}$  is a $\pi$-system generating the product $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb R \times \Omega$. Let $$\mathcal H:=\{Y_{s}(\omega): Y_{s}(\omega) \text{ is bounded jointly measurable and } \phi(y,s) = E^y(Y_s) \text{ is jointly Borel measurable}\}$$
Firstly, constant $1 \in \mathcal H$ is obvious.
Secondly, $U\times B \in \mathcal P \implies 1_{U\times B} \in \mathcal H$ follows from STEP3. Lastly, $0\leq Y_n \uparrow Y $ for some $Y_n \in \mathcal H$ and $Y$ bounded implies $Y\in \mathcal H$ by MCT and the fact that pointwise limit of measurable is measurable.

Thus, by monotone class theorem, $\mathcal H$ contain all bounded $\sigma(\mathcal P)$ measurable function, which yields the result.